# How to change color from QColorDialog with MouseMoveEvent

Tags: python, pyqt5

When i click `QPushButton`, a `QColorDialog` opens. My question is:
how do i change the color of `QWidget` in `mouseMoveEvent` of `QColorDialog`

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import sys

class ColorPicker(QColorDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.color = None
        self.colorpicker = ColorPicker()
        self.colorChooser = QPushButton("ColorChooser", self)
        self.colorChooser.clicked.connect(self.onColorPicker)
        self.colorChooser.move(10, 10)

    def onColorPicker(self):
        self.get_color = self.colorpicker.getColor()
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color:%s;" % self.get_color.name())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.setFixedSize(400, 400)
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Could you explain me better, what you point out is confusing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### tl;dr - no, you can't

Unfortunately, QColorDialog doesn't support this kind of interaction. The standard dialog tries to use the system's native color picker dialog, which doesn't provide any API, besides returning the selected color, and the "non-native" dialog has only private methods and objects that are not easily accessible from PyQt.

I think that what you need *could* be achieved using a non-native dialog, but it's very difficult, as one should "browse" through the dialog's children, find the "color shower" widget and then install an event filter to get its mouseMoveEvents, then use [`grab()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#grab) or [`render()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#render) to get a widget screenshot, transform it to a QImage and get the color of the pixel. But that wouldn't be safe, mostly because, being it a "hardcoded" dialog, its content might change in the future; long story short, it's possible that across different versions (even minor) of Qt, that won't work as expected. Also, since the color shower has a "cross cursor" to show the current color, you might risk that, by hovering over it, you'll only get the cross cursor color, making all aforementioned efforts useless.

### Alternative solution: create your own color picker

[image: screenshot of the custom color picker example]

Some time ago I created a more complex tool for color picking, as I was unsatisfied with what Qt provides: I work mostly on Linux (which does not have an *actual* native color dialog) and I required features I've seen on both Windows and MacOS, plus other things that Qt4 version of QColorDialog had which were missing on Qt5's counterpart (and viceversa).
Luckily for you, I've been able to recycle part of it for this, as I found out how the color shower is painted and how you can get a color using your mouse. Note that in my tool I also created a "color wheel" (the color ring with a gradient triangle in the middle), but that's a bit more complicated.
This example will show a small dialog with the color picker, and automatically sets its color to the current one. Moving the mouse automatically updates the background of the main widget, but that will be applied only if the dialog is accepted (by clicking Ok or pressing Enter/Return).

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class RgbPicker(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    # create a vertical color gradient similar to the "Color Shower"
    # used in QColorDialog
    colorGrads = QtGui.QLinearGradient(0, 0, 1, 0)
    colorGrads.setCoordinateMode(colorGrads.ObjectBoundingMode)
    xRatio = 1. / 6
    colorGrads.setColorAt(0, QtCore.Qt.red)
    colorGrads.setColorAt(1, QtCore.Qt.red)
    colorGrads.setColorAt(xRatio, QtCore.Qt.magenta)
    colorGrads.setColorAt(xRatio * 2, QtCore.Qt.blue)
    colorGrads.setColorAt(xRatio * 3, QtCore.Qt.cyan)
    colorGrads.setColorAt(xRatio * 4, QtCore.Qt.green)
    colorGrads.setColorAt(xRatio * 5, QtCore.Qt.yellow)

    # add a "mask" gradient to support gradients to lighter colors
    maskGrad = QtGui.QLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 1)
    maskGrad.setCoordinateMode(maskGrad.ObjectBoundingMode)
    maskGrad.setColorAt(0, QtCore.Qt.transparent)
    maskGrad.setColorAt(1, QtCore.Qt.white)

    # create a cross cursor to show the selected color, if any
    cursorPath = QtGui.QPainterPath()
    cursorPath.moveTo(-10, 0)
    cursorPath.lineTo(-4, 0)
    cursorPath.moveTo(0, -10)
    cursorPath.lineTo(0, -4)
    cursorPath.moveTo(4, 0)
    cursorPath.lineTo(10, 0)
    cursorPath.moveTo(0, 4)
    cursorPath.lineTo(0, 10)
    cursorPen = QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.black, 3)

    colorChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QtGui.QColor)
    showCursor = False
    cursorPos = QtCore.QPoint()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.setFixedSize(220, 200)
        # create a pixmap and paint it with the gradients
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(self.size())
        qp = QtGui.QPainter(pixmap)
        qp.fillRect(pixmap.rect(), self.colorGrads)
        qp.fillRect(pixmap.rect(), self.maskGrad)
        qp.end()
        self.setPixmap(pixmap)
        # a QImage is required to get the color of a specific pixel
        self.image = pixmap.toImage()
        self.currentColor = QtGui.QColor()

    def setColor(self, color):
        self.currentColor = color
        # compute the cursor coordinates according to the color values;
        # this is based on Hue/Saturation/Value data of the color
        h, s, v, a = color.getHsv()
        x = (360 - h) * (self.width() - 1) / 360.
        y = (255 - s) * (self.height() - 1) / 255.
        self.cursorPos = QtCore.QPoint(x, y)
        self.showCursor = True
        self.update()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            # set the current color and emit the colorChanged signal
            self.currentColor = QtGui.QColor(self.image.pixel(event.pos()))
            self.cursorPos = event.pos()
            self.showCursor = True
            self.update()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.pos() in self.rect():
            color = QtGui.QColor(self.image.pixel(event.pos()))
            self.colorChanged.emit(color)
            if event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
                # if the left button is pressed, update the current color
                self.currentColor = color
                self.cursorPos = event.pos()
                self.update()

    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        # emit the previously selected color when leaving
        self.colorChanged.emit(self.currentColor)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        # paint the "color shower"
        QtWidgets.QLabel.paintEvent(self, event)
        if self.showCursor:
            # paint the color "cursor"
            qp = QtGui.QPainter(self)
            qp.setPen(self.cursorPen)
            qp.translate(self.cursorPos)
            qp.drawPath(self.cursorPath)


class ColorPicker(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    colorChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QtGui.QColor)
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.rgbPicker = RgbPicker(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.rgbPicker)
        self.rgbPicker.colorChanged.connect(self.colorChanged)

        buttonBox = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok|QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel)
        layout.addWidget(buttonBox)
        buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.reject)

    def getColor(self, color=None):
        if isinstance(color, QtGui.QColor):
            self.rgbPicker.setColor(color)
        # return a color only if the dialog is accepted
        if self.exec_():
            return self.rgbPicker.currentColor

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # get the current background color, should we ignore the picker selection
        self.color = self.palette().color(QtGui.QPalette.Window)
        self.colorPicker = ColorPicker(self)
        self.colorPicker.colorChanged.connect(self.setcolorChanged)
        self.colorChooser = QtWidgets.QPushButton("ColorChooser", self)
        self.colorChooser.clicked.connect(self.onColorPicker)
        self.colorChooser.move(10, 10)

    def setcolorChanged(self, color):
        # set the stylesheet *only* for this class, not its children, otherwise
        # you'll set the background for both the button *and* the color picker
        self.setStyleSheet("MainWindow { background-color:%s;}" % color.name())

    def onColorPicker(self):
        color = self.colorPicker.getColor(self.color)
        # update the color only if the dialog is accepted: if the user presses
        # Esc, it will be ignored
        if color:
            print('ok', color.getRgb())
            self.color = color
        self.setcolorChanged(self.color)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```